# Mailing a dynamic form with ASP

Tags: asp.net, forms, email

I asked a similar question last week regarding a PHP mailer, but it now turns out I need to use ASP:

I have a form that dynamically adds inputs depending on a user-supplied number. The form is used for booking courses, and the user selects the number of attendees, with the form adding in inputs to read in their details.

The inputs are generated and named simply by inserting the count of a FOR loop into the relevant attributes:

```
var inputEl = $('<input type="text" class="text delegate" name="delegate_name_' + i + '" id="delegate-name-' + i + '" placeholder="Delegate Name ' + (i + 1) + '" /><input type="text" class="text delegate" name="delegate_email_' + i + '" id="delegate-email-' + i + '" placeholder="Delegate Email ' + (i + 1) + '" /><input type="text" class="text delegate" name="delegate_tel_' + i + '" id="delegate-tel-' + i + '" placeholder="Delegate Telephone ' + (i + 1) + '" />')
```

This is all fine and dandy and works fine. However, I am about to write the ASP for mailing the form, and the thought occurs to me that I don't know how to tell the mail script how many inputs it needs to read.

Once I've got the inputs I need to add them to the body of the e-mail.

The PHP solution was to store the dynamic entries in an array and then loop through that. I have no idea whether I can or  how to do that with ASP.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same idea as PHP:

- Classic ASP: Request Object -> [Form Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- ASP.Net - these are the "basics", you can get into MVC and models but these should do

  - [HttpRequest.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx)
  - [HttpUtility.ParseQuerySTring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx)

Hth...